# How to get a value for each character in a string in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, character

I am creating a program where the code needs to get a value from each character in a string (that can vary in length). Such as a name, an example, Tony, where T = 1, O = 4, N = 7, Y = 3. This has to add to a total. I have tried loops but only getting 1 as an output, even if there isn't a character that has a value in the string.

```
Dim FNTL As Integer = Nothing

    Dim FN = FN_TBX.Text
    For Each A, J, S As Char In FN_TBX.Text
        FNTL = +8
    Next

    Dim FNTLstr
    FNTLstr = Convert.ToString(FNTL)
    LN_TBX.Text = FNTL
```

FN_TBX is the textbox input
FN is the textbox input
FNTL is the total
FNstr is the total in string format

Some characters have the same value such as above, A, J, S are = to 8. The integer conversion is to display the total to a text box.

Comment: What is the rule for this: `T = 1, O = 4, N = 7, Y = 3`?

Comment: The value of those characters, the rule doesn't follow a regular pattern.

Comment: What does mean "For Each A, J, S As Char In FN_TBX.Text" ?

Comment: cicciorocca, For each A/ J/ S character in the string add 8 to FNTL

Comment: Do you Know that it won't compile? Is it just pseudo-code?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `FNTL =+ 8`? And what does FN do? It's never used.

Comment: Yeah I know, it is in vb, but I put that in as an example, would I have to do it separately then? There isn't a way to do it in one line of code?

Comment: topshot, VB changes it to that, i use FN further on

Comment: Ok! @TimSchmelter gave you a nice piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is not entirely clear. Maybe you should have a `Dictionary(Of Char, Int32)` to get a value for each char and a fallback-value if it's not defined.

Here is an example with a dictionary which is declared as class field:

```
Dim _charValue As New Dictionary(Of Char, Int32) From
{
        {"t"c, 1}, {"T"c, 1},
        {"o"c, 4}, {"O"c, 4},
        {"n"c, 7}, {"N"c, 7},
        {"y"c, 3}, {"Y"c, 3},
        {"a"c, 8}, {"A"c, 8},
        {"j"c, 8}, {"J"c, 8},
        {"s"c, 8}, {"S"c, 8}
}
```

Now you can calculate the sum in your method, for example with a simple loop:

```
Dim sum as Int32 = 0
For Each c As Char In FN_TBX.Text
    Dim charValue = 0
    If Not _charValue.TryGetValue(c, charValue)
        charValue = 1 ' fallback value
    End If
    sum += charValue 
Next
LN_TBX.Text = sum.ToString()
```

Comment: Very nice interpretation!